Laravel 10 Call to undefined method Staudenmeir\LaravelCte\Query\Builder::() despite correct instance
I'm working on a Laravel 10 project. I've got a service that checks the Perk eligibility of a user and constructs some queries, I'm getting the following error:

Call to undefined method Staudenmeir\LaravelCte\Query\Builder::()

But after checking the type of checkEligibilityForUser it's certainly Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder so I don't know what I'm missing, here's my class and how it's being called:
Service
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\PerkEligibilityContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use App\Models\Perk;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Throwable;

class PerkEligibilityService implements PerkEligibilityContract
{
    /**
     * The perk
     */
    private Perk $perk;

    /**
     * The user id for lookup
     */
    private int $userId;

    /**
     * The user ids for lookup
     */
    private array $userIds;

    /**
     * Validate and return operator
     */
    private function validateOperator(string $operator): string
    {
        return match ($operator) {
            '!=' => '!=',
            '>' => '>',
            '>=' => '>=',
            '<' => '<',
            '<=' => '<=',
            default => '='
        };
    }

    /**
     * Return the current date or date specified
     */
    private function currentDate(string $date = 'now'): Carbon
    {
        try {
            return Carbon::parse($date);
        } catch (Throwable $err) {
            return Carbon::now();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate relative date
     *
     * ">=" - refers to "In the last N days", so any date from them to now
     * "<=" - refers to "More than N days", so any date before a given date not up to now
     */
    private function relativeDate(string $value, string $operator = '>='): Carbon
    {
        [$amount, $unit] = explode(':', $value);

        $now = $this->currentDate();

        return match ($unit) {
            'second', 'seconds' => $operator === '>=' ? $now->subSeconds((int) $amount) : $now->addSeconds((int) $amount),
            'minute', 'minutes' => $operator === '>=' ? $now->subMinutes((int) $amount) : $now->addMinutes((int) $amount),
            'hour', 'hours' => $operator === '>=' ? $now->subHours((int) $amount) : $now->addHours((int) $amount),
            'day', 'days' => $operator === '>=' ? $now->subDays((int) $amount) : $now->addDays((int) $amount),
            'week', 'weeks' => $operator === '>=' ? $now->subWeeks((int) $amount) : $now->addWeeks((int) $amount),
            'month', 'months' => $operator === '>=' ? $now->subMonths((int) $amount) : $now->addMonths((int) $amount),
            'year', 'years' => $operator === '>=' ? $now->subYears((int) $amount) : $now->subYears((int) $amount),
            default => $now
        };
    }

    /**
     * Validate and return value
     */
    private function validateValue(string $dataType, string $operatorType, string $operator, mixed $value): mixed
    {
        return match ($dataType) {
            'number' => (int) $value,
            'date' => match ($operatorType) {
                'relative' => $this->relativeDate($value, $operator),
                default => $this->currentDate('now')
            },
            default => $value
        };
    }

    /**
     * Apply query condition
     */
    private function applyQueryCondition(object $rule, Builder $query, string $column = ''): void
    {
        if (! Schema::hasColumn($query->getModel()->getTable(), $column ?? '')) return;

        // modify the value based on data type and dynamic field
        $value = $this->validateValue(
            $rule->data_type, $rule->operator_type, $this->validateOperator($rule->operator), $rule->value
        );

        // no need to return, query is directly applied back on $query instance
        match ($rule->operator) {
            'like' => $query->where($column, 'like', $value),
            '%like%' => $query->where($column, 'like', "%$value%"),
            'like%' => $query->where($column, 'like', "$value%"),
            '%like' => $query->where($column, 'like', "%$value"),
            'is_empty' => $query->where($column, '=', ''),
            'not_empty' => $query->where($column, '!=', ''),
            'is_null' => $query->whereNull($column),
            'not_null' => $query->whereNotNull($column),
            default => $query->where($column, $this->validateOperator($rule->operator), $value)
        };
    }

    /**
     * Check the eligibility
     */
    private function checkEligibilityConditions(Builder $models): void
    {
        $this->perk->rules->each(function (object $rule) use ($models) {
            if (Str::contains($rule->attribute, '.')) {
                $collection = Str::of($rule->attribute)->explode('.');
                $relationship = $collection->slice(0, -1)->implode('.');
                $column = $collection->last();

                $models->whereHas($relationship, function (Builder $query) use ($rule, $column) {
                    $this->applyQueryCondition($rule, $query, $column);
                });
            } else {
                $this->applyQueryCondition($rule, $models, $rule->attribute);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Check the eligibility for the user
     */
    private function checkEligibilityForUser(): bool
    {
        $user = User::query()->where('id', $this->userId);

        $this->checkEligibilityConditions($user);

        return $user->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Check the eligibility for the users
     */
    private function checkEligibilityForUsers(): int
    {
        $users = User::query()->whereIn('id', $this->userIds);

        $this->checkEligibilityConditions($users);

        return $users->count();
    }

    /**
     * Set's the perk
     */
    public function perk(Perk $perk): self
    {
        $this->perk = $perk->load(['rules' => fn ($query) => $query->enabled()]);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set's the user id
     */
    public function userId(int $userId): self
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set's the user ids
     */
    public function userIds(array $userIds): self
    {
        $this->userIds = $userIds;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get a count of users that are eligible
     */
    public function areEligible(): int
    {
        if ($this->perk->rules->isNotEmpty()) {
            return $this->checkEligibilityForUsers();
        }

        return count($this->userIds);
    }

    /**
     * Is the user eligible
     */
    public function isEligible(): bool
    {
        if ($this->perk->rules->isNotEmpty()) {
            return $this->checkEligibilityForUser();
        }

        return true;
    }
}

Called as:
$perk = Perk::find($request->input('id')
$user = auth()->user();

PerkEligibility::perk($perk)->userId($user->id)->isEligible()


So, where does the code give the error exactly? I mean its not easy to deduce as a 3rd party without having a callstack :)

This isn't a third party. I wrote EligibilityService. That's the code attached, the error is a Laravel error.

I mean, we as readers on stack overflow, are 3rd party ;)


i see you share definition of PerkEligibilityService, yet you are using PerkEligibility. Is it the same class with a different alias?


Yes, it's a Facade

So which of the 3 functions cause the error?

It's in the description checkEligibilityForUser :)

In description you mention you did some typecheck, not necessarily that this function is the culprit. The function itself does not contain any weird code. Might it be in checkEligibilityConditions() or one of the subcalls? Like, does it crash when commenting out checkEligibilityConditions call?
